# Assignement problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I had a lecture about linear optimization and I was told that in the linear assignement problem, there always is an optimal solution where the variables take integer values. This intrigues me and the Wikipedia page says that " This is because the constraint matrix of the fractional LP is totally unmodular – it satisfies the four conditions of Hoffman and Gale. " (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Assignment_problem)

Could I get an explanation about the conditions of Hoffman and Gale?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Common totally unimodular matrices" subsection in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix can be a good start. It is a certain sufficient condition for a matrix to be totally unimodular, which guarantees that LP solutions are integral. See that whole "Total unimodularity" section in wikipedia for more info.